# Why dim(Ker(A)+dim Im(A)) not equal N?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathscr A$ be a linear transformation on an n-dimensional linear space $V$ ($n\geqslant 3 $), take a set of bases $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_n$ in $V$, def $\mathscr{A}\left(\alpha_{i}\right)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}\textbf{0}, i=1,2 \\ \alpha_{3}, i=3, \cdots, n\end{array}\right.$

Then, $Ker(\mathscr A)= L(\alpha_1 ,\alpha_2)$, $\mathscr A V=L(\alpha_3)$

$\dim Ker(\mathscr A) = 2$,$\dim \mathscr A V =1$

why $\dim Ker(\mathscr A) +\dim \mathscr A V = 3 \neq n$ ?

Comment: Think about what space each of those spaces live in

Comment: The kernel is much more than just the linear span of $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ when $n\geq 4$. For example, it also contains any vector of the form $\kappa_3\alpha_3+\cdots+\kappa_n\alpha_n$ in which $\kappa_3+\cdots+\kappa_n=0$. Thus, $\alpha_3-\alpha_4$ is in the kernel, for example. In other words: it's not adding up because you are miscomputing the kernel.

Comment: While the image can be found by just looking at what happens to basis vectors, the kernel cannot be found just by looking at which basis vectors map to zero.

Comment: I know now. The answer on the book is wrong

Comment: Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel has dimension $n-1$ and the image has dimension $1$. The sum is indeed $n$. For example, not only do $a_1$ and $a_2$ get sent to zero, but since $a_3$ and $a_4$ both map to $a_3$, the difference $a_3-a_4$ maps to zero.

One basis for the kernel is $\{a_1,a_2,a_3-a_4,a_3-a_5,\ldots, a_3-a_n\}$. You can show these vectors are linearly independent, so the null space is $(n-1)$-dimensional.